# Flex 3.5: Not able to retrieve the children of VBOX inside a tab navigator

Tags: flex3, adobe

I have 2 VBox inside a tabNavigator.

The code snippet of VBox I am interested is as below

```
<mx:TabNavigator  id ="tabNav">

<mx:VBox label="Class Details" name="clsDetail" id="ClsDetails" height="301" width="300" >
       <mx:FormItem label="PropID"  name="PropoId" id="propoIDForm" direction="horizontal">
            <mx:NumericStepper id="propagatedIDInput" name ="objId"  minimum="0" maximum="100" stepSize="1" width="65"/>
       </mx:FormItem>

<mx:FormItem label="Difficulty" direction="horizontal">
                    <mx:RadioButtonGroup id="difficulty"/>
                    <mx:RadioButton label="Easy" groupName="difficulty" value="1"/>
                    <mx:RadioButton label="Medium" groupName="difficulty" value="2"/>
                    <mx:RadioButton label="Hard" groupName="difficulty" value="3"/>
          </mx:FormItem>

</mx:VBox>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

I am trying to set the Numeric stepper runtime and I am not able to do it. Tried 2 approaches

```
Approach 1: iterate through children and get the one

   var VBoxChildren:Array = ClsDetails.getChildren();
   for each(var currentFormItem:FormItem in VBoxChildren)
    {
     var FormChildren:Array = currentFormItem.getChildren(); //somehow it is becoming null
       for each(var currentItem:* in FormChildren) //doesn't go in since the array is null)
            {
              if(currentItem is NumericStepper)
                {
                 (currentItem as NumericStepper).value = int(markedObject.propagatedID);
                }
            }
      }

Approach 2: try to get children byname

  var myVBox:VBox = tabNav.getChildByName("clsDetail") as VBox;

   var frmItem:FormItem = myVBox.getChildByName("PropoId") as FormItem;//issue it becomes null ..somhownot able to get this children even though it is visible when I debug

    var  objId:NumericStepper = frmItem.getChildByName("objId") as NumericStepper; undefined as above is null
```

I am not sure what am I missing here  ...suggestions most appreciated!!

```
Thanks
Akshay
```

Comment: why you are using that much coding? i dint understand! cant you directly assign value during runtime like `propagatedIDInput.value=int(markedObject.propagatedID);` ?

Comment: actually I was trying to do that in the first place. but all along Unknown by deffered instantiation I was not getting the reference if the Numeric stepper since it wasn't getting initialized...then it struck me and I set the creationPolicy = all (which sorta defeats the purpose ) and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted my question on adobe forum and the response solved it...actually the issue of deffered instantiation was not setting my child components inside a tabnavigator and were setting just VBox ( the first child)...

All I was missing was to set creationPolicy = all(as explained by my comments above) ...and it worked like charm..

Here's a good read on PureMVC about deffered instatiation of Flex components http://puremvc.org/content/view/91/188/